# Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *' from 'AVAssetReaderOutput *'

Tags: ios, gpuimage, avassetreader

I am getting a warning 'incompatible pointer types assigning to 'AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *' from 'AVAssetReaderOutput *'' while using GPUImage library. I have edited 'GPUImageMovie.m' so as to enable audio playback as suggested [here](https://github.com/tuo/GPUImage/commit/b96d2d1ab43d99b018066d86834cce914cf02171#diff-3e26e3d864e87ba9a514ba4bee917e5dR672).

Please help me to remove this warning.